# Is there a mechanism to cast, as a single action, a spell with a 10 minute cast time?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat

What methods there are to use Prayer of Healing (or similar long casts) in combat?

*This question follows a comment on ["Does casting a 10 minute spell really take 100 rounds of combat?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76231/25601)*

Answer (score 12):

There are several ways to do this.

### Wish

You can cast any spell of 8th level or lower, ignoring the material requirements or the casting time duration, as one action.

### Glyph Of Warding

This also doesn't use up one action, but again on the same lines.

Glyph is a 3rd level spell that has a spell glyph mode. You cast this spell and another spell of the same level, which must be harmful to the one that triggered it. Similar to Contingency, you set a trigger for it, and it happens on the first trigger. The extra restriction is you must cast it over a surface (a wall, floor, etc) or an object that can be closed (a book). If cast on an object, that object cannot be moved more than 10 feet from the point of casting. If moved, the spell is broken without triggering. If the spell requires concentration, it lasts for the full duration without requiring concentration.

For every level cast higher than 3rd, you can also prepare a spell one level higher.

## Invalid Answers

1. **Ring of Spell Storing** - This does not change the cast time of spells. The details can be found in the accepted answer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76556/how-does-a-ring-of-spell-storing-function).
2. **Contingency** - You can only make contingent spells with a 1 action cast time

Comment: *Contingency* will only work on spells with a casting time of one action. Nothing in the description of *Ring of Spell Storing* allows a user to change the casting time of spells.

Comment: @MarkCogan I would say there is room for interpretation. After all, once a spell with a 10 minute cast time has been cast, it will expend a spell slot and the spell will be stored in the ring. I would argue that you perform a "Use item" action rather than a "spellcasting" action when using the ring, and once the spell is cast from the ring, you are designated as the caster (for purposes of concentration, etc).

Comment: @MarkCogan I stand corrected, using Ring of Spell Storing is **not** a Use Object action. I will remove that item from my answer. Source: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/525302987351007235

Answer (score 6):

If the spell is cast at level 5, or less, yes. Among the Magic items listed in the DMG, there is a fanciful ring that can act as a preparatory reservoir for spells, called the Ring of Spell Storing.

In advance of combat, during downtime or prior to a Long Rest, the spell user casts a spell as normal, mostly. The deviation is that the spell is cast into the ring.

A Ring of Spell Storing, as described by the DMG, can hold up to 5 spell levels, be it one level 5 spell or five level 1 spells, in any combination.

Comment: _While wearing this ring, you can cast any spell stored in it. The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell attack bonus, and spellcasting ability of the original caster, but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell._ It's not clear from this that casting a spell from the ring takes any less time than casting it normally.

Comment: @xrode I would argue that it is clear. Casting time is not changed.

Comment: I acknowledge the above statements; trying to see if I can identify a justification that proves me right.

Comment: The justification is as follows: DMG pg. 192 "The ring stores spells **cast** into it...." That's the important bit. The spell is cast into the ring to store it. Which means it doesn't matter how long it takes to cast the spell, the end result is the same. A successfully cast spell is stored in the ring and can be released as if the person wielding the ring had cast the spell. Which means when you use your action to "cast a spell using the ring," all you are doing is releasing the spell you have stored within it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an incorrect answer. See this question: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76556/how-does-a-ring-of-spell-storing-function

Comment: @markovchain - I'm in the midst of disagreeing with that question and answer.