# How does a Ring of Spell Storing function?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The Ring of Spell Storing says (DMG pg. 192):

> This ring stores spells cast into it, holding them until the attuned wearer uses them. The ring can store up to 5 levels worth of spells at a time. When found, it contains 1d6 — 1 levels of stored spells chosen by the DM.
>   Any creature can cast a spell of 1st through 5th level into the ring by touching the ring as the spell is cast. The spell has no effect, other than to be stored in the ring. If the ring can't hold the spell, the spell is expended without effect. The level of the slot used to cast the spell determines how much space it uses.
>
> While wearing this ring, you can cast any spell stored in it. The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell attack bonus, and spellcasting ability of the original caster, but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell. The spell cast from the ring is no longer stored in it, freeing up space.

So the question is, exactly how does this item work in it's totality? A great answer will have references that point to specific functionality that are cited and sourced from the official D&D 5e material.

1. Do you cast the spells by performing the necessary components and then releasing it?

   OR
2. Do you simply release the stored spell?

   AND
3. How are actions applied if at all?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Spells cast from the ring use normal actions and no components.**

Many magic items allow the user to cast spells. The general rules for this are on p. 141 of the DMG, under the *Spells* subsection of *Activating an Item*:

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires **no components**, unless the item's description says otherwise. The spell uses its **normal casting time**, range, and duration, and the user of the item must concentrate if the spell requires concentration.

(emphases mine).

Beyond these rules for magic items, casting a spell follows the rules in the Player's Handbook; generally, the character casting the spell takes the Cast a Spell action on their turn.

Here's what the *Ring of Spell Storing* says about casting the spells in it (DMG, p. 192:

> While wearing this ring, you can **cast any spell** stored in it. The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell attack bonus, and spellcasting ability of the original caster, but is **otherwise treated as if you cast the spell**.

Let's look at two examples of stored spells being cast:

1. *Fireball* stored in the ring at 3rd level by a 10th Level School of Evocation wizard with a save DC of 16
2. *Magic Circle* stored in the ring at 5th level by a 11th level Cleric with a save DC of 17.

*Fireball*, cast from the ring by a 3rd level Sorcerer (save DC 14):

- Will require one action to cast (same as the spell)
- Will do 8D6 damage; the original casting wizard's Empowered Evocation feature will not apply since it is not one of the characteristics that the ring lists as being 'stored'.
- Can be used with *Quickened Spell* by the casting sorcerer, since that falls under being "treated as if you cast the spell".
- Will have a save DC of 16, from the original caster.

*Magic Circle*, cast from the ring by a 19th level Fighter:

- Will require one minute to cast (same as the spell).
- Will not require any chalk or other material components, even though that is normally required.
- Will have a duration of three hours (base duration plus two extra hours for using a 5th level slot).
- The fighter has no spellcasting ability, and thus no spell save DC, but the *Magic Circle* will have a save DC of 17.

Comment: I first thought this may not apply, since the Ring specifies that it uses the slot level of the original caster, not the lowest level like the general rule mentions. Then I realized that the Ring 'says otherwise' for the Spell Level, but not the other two general rules. Good answer!

Comment: The fighter doesn't exactly have "no spell save DC". DMG page 141: "If you don't have a spellcasting ability-perhaps you're a rogue with the Use Magic Device feature- your spellcasting ability modifier is +0 for the item, and your proficiency bonus does apply."

Spell save DC is 8 + spellcasting modifier + proficiency bonus, so the save DC of a level 19 Fighter's spells should be 8+0+6=14.

(This doesn't change the correctness above. The DC 17 of the original Cleric remains)

Answer (score 4):

You simply cast the spell.  The spells stored in the ring have already had their components "applied" when the spells were originally cast.  When you cast a spell while touching the ring, you cast the spell as normal, including any verbal, somatic, or material components, and you can store the spell in the ring as long as the ring can take the spell.

> The spell uses its normal casting time, range, and duration, and the user of the item must concentrate if the spell requires concentration.

While wearing it, you can cast any of those spells.  It's similar to using a scroll, using "the slot level, spell save DC, spell attack bonus, and spellcasting ability of the original caster" but as if you had cast it.