# Does a spell stored in a weapon, using spell storing, keep the bonuses of the original caster

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

So looking over [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76556/how-does-a-ring-of-spell-storing-function%27) for 5th edition made me wonder if it is usually considered the same in 3.5 since it is not specified.

> **Spell Storing:** A spell storing weapon allows a spellcaster to store a single targeted spell of up to 3rd level in the weapon. The weapon strikes a creature and the creature takes damage from it,the weapon can immediately cast the spell on that creature as a free action if the wielder desires. This special ability is an exception to the general rule that casting a spell from an item takes a least as long as casting that spell normally.... Once the spell has been cast from the weapon, a spellcaster can cast any other targeted spell of up to 3rd level into it. The weapon magically imparts to the wielder the name of the spell currently stored within it."(*DMG*,225)

So because of the last bit, is the wielder considered the caster for bonus purposes or is it the original caster? Is it considered the weapon? For example the damage added from a warmage's Int modifier from "warmage edge:... Whenever a warmage casts a spell that deals hit point damage, he adds his intelligence bonus (if any) to the amount of damage dealt...." (*Miniatures Handbook*, 15). Will the spell stored in the weapon retain the damage bonus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Spell storing: A spell storing weapon allows a spellcaster to store a
>   single targeted spell of up to 3rd level in the weapon.(The weapon
>   strikes a creature and the creature takes damage from it,**the weapon
>   can immediately cast the spell** on that creature as a free action if
>   the wielder desires. (This special ability is an exception to the
>   general rule that casting a spell from an item takes a least as long
>   as casting that spell normally.)... Once the spell has been cast from
>   the weapon, a spellcaster can cast any other targeted spell of up to
>   3rd level into it. The weapon magically imparts to the wielder the
>   name of the spell currently stored within it."(DMG,225)

The weapon casts the spell, not the wielder. Treat is as if the wielder was using UMD to activate a wand or scroll. I don't think the warmage's bonus would apply as he is not casting the spell, the weapon is (if a warmage were to make a scroll, the bonus would not carry through).

Answer (score 2):

From *Warmage Edge* :

> Scrolls scribed by a warmage do not gain any benefit from warmage
>   edge. Scrolls activated by a warmage also gain no benefit from warmage
>   edge. The same is true for most other magic items, such as wands and
>   potions.

As Gaynorvader said,

> The weapon casts the spell, not the wielder. Treat is as if the
>   wielder was using UMD to activate a wand or scroll.

Therefore a spell cast by a warmage stored in a spell-storing weapon doesn't benefit from *warmage edge*.

In a more general way, when a wizard casts a spell from a scroll, he doesn't use **his** casting abilities (for determining variables based on caster level : duration, range, ... ; or his ability score for calculating DC). Likewise, a warmage can't add his *warmage edge* on a spell cast from a scroll.

Comment: Can you site "for determining...DC"?  CL (and thus duration/range) is determined when scribing the scroll (increased cost equals higher CL) but I see nothing about DC.  I do recall a rule (but couldn't find it) where you aquired a random scroll you assumed the stat was minimal for determining DC, but in the case of knowing the caster, I assumed it'd be factored in.  I realize this is a partial Q on A but I think knowing a sitation would improve the answer and also lend to me giving a +1 (it disagrees with rules that I believe true).  I agree with the rest, fwiw=)

Comment: @joedragons Well the DC is spell's level + Relevant ability modifier : in the case of a scroll, the ability of the character who wrote it and not the ability of the character using it.

Comment: Cool, I agree with that but that's not how I read what you said.  FYI, I'm still +1ing with the clarification given here but I personally think it'd be better if you removed "DC" from above as it could be misconstrued.

Comment: @joedragons I clariified it :)